# Return Value from Callable Function

Tags: python, function, typing

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#Sentience

import typing

Ninf = typing.Callable[[int], bool]

Ninf_map = typing.Callable[[Ninf], bool]

def inj(k: int) -> Ninf:
    return lambda n: n < k

def eps(p : Ninf_map) -> Ninf:
    return lambda n: min(p(inj(k)) for k in range(n + 1))

def omniscience(p : Ninf_map) -> typing.Optional[Ninf]:
    return None if p(x := eps(p)) else x

inj
eps
omniscience

s = x
if s:
    print("XOXO")
```

As you see here, x has no value, but in function “omniscience” it is assigned.

I would like to know how to retrieve “x” in this case…

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? May be you want to call function `omniscience` with some argument e.g., `omniscience(2)` at the end of your code to get the output "success"?

Comment: @user9099684: Type annotations aren't enforced at runtime, so you could pass literally anything and it would work. If you want to obey the type annotations, you just need to define a function that accepts something matching `Ninf_map`'s protocol (you don't even need a function that actually adheres to `Ninf`'s protocol, it just needs to accept one if it exists) and pass it to `omniscience`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function omniscience with an argument

```
omniscience(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "call `omniscience` with an appropriate argument". At runtime, `p` can be *anything*, since you don't actually use it. If you are performing static type-checking, `p` has to be a function (or more precisely, something you can call), even though `p` is never called or used. (Type checkers only worry about matching signatures, not about runtime behavior.)

Let's look at `Ninf`: it's basically a *predicate* on integers. Some examples might be named `even`, `odd`, `greater_than_zero`, etc. It takes a number, and returns `True` or `False` based on some property of the number.

Let's take a look at `Ninf_map`. It's *another* predicate, but this time on a predicate itself. We're at a level of abstraction that's a little harder to grasp. What kind of predicates can we define on a predicate? We can't really "examine" the predicate; all we can do is call it on some arguments and see what it returns in each case

Here's a trivial example.

```
# satisfiable has type Ninf_map. It will return
# true if there is *some* number n for which p(n) is true.
def statisfiable(p: Ninf) -> bool:
    if p(0):
        return True
    for n in count(1):
        if p(n) or p(-n):
            return True
    return False
```

(Note that `satisfiable` can never return `False`; it either returns `True` or it runs forever. But, the *type* is OK, which is all we care about here.)

Because `satisfiable` has type `Callable[[Ninf],bool]`, it is a valid argument to `omniscience`, regardless of whether `omniscience` uses it or not.

```
omniscience(satisfiable)  # This type checks; satisfiable has the correct type.
```